# How do you retrieve results from a service layer/repository with Moq?

Tags: c#, service, repository, moq

I have a little bit of a problem with Moq. I have created a fake repository with a fake service class so I can show you where I am getting the problem.

If you see below I have only got an `Add()` and `GetAllStrings()` method in my repository, which are used in the `FakeService` class to do the `AddFakeThings()` and `GetallTheFakeThings(`). The problem is, when I add strings inside my repository using the service class, the list of the service class doesn't increment, so I will never be able to test if the items are added inside.

Why is that?

I have seen solutions where people create fake repositories with the data inside, but that is too messy to test an enterprise solution, is there any other way?

```
//## Interface for Fake Repository    

public interface IFakeRepo
{
        void Add(string something);
        IList<string> GetAllStrings();
}


//## Fake Repository

public class FakeRepo:IFakeRepo
{
        private List<string> mylist;
        public FakeRepo()
        {
            mylist = new List<string>();
        }
        public void Add(string something)
        {
            mylist.Add(something);
        }
        public IList<string> GetAllStrings()
        {
            return mylist;
        }
}

//## Interface for the Fake Service

public interface IFakeService
{
        void AddAFakeThing(string thing);
        IList<string> GetAllTheFakeThings();       
}

//## Fake Service

public class FakeService: IFakeService
{ 
         private IFakeRepo _fakerepo;
         public FakeService(IFakeRepo fakerepo)
         {
             _fakerepo = fakerepo;
         }
         public void AddAFakeThing(string thing)
         {
             _fakerepo.Add(thing);
         }
         public IList<string> GetAllTheFakeThings()
         {
            return _fakerepo.GetAllStrings();
         }
}
```

//## This is what I am testing... the result should be 3 or 1 as I am adding 3 strings to the Repo or 1 string with the service and they are null

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_Fake_Class()
    {
        //## Creating my fake repo
        var _mFakeRepo = new Mock<IFakeRepo>();
        //## Init Fake Service
        var service = new FakeService(_mFakeRepo.Object);
        //## Adding strings
        _mFakeRepo.Setup(x => x.Add("hello2"));
        _mFakeRepo.Setup(x => x.Add("Bye2"));
        _mFakeRepo.Setup(x => x.Add("hola2"));
        service.AddAFakeThing("hahaha");
        //## I suppose to get a result
        //## BUT I AM NOT GETTING ANYTHING... WHERE IS THE DATA FROM THE REPO
        var result = service.GetAllTheFakeThings();
        //## This should work
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Count == 3);
        //## Or this...
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Count == 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you are using Moq? You implemented all the code yourself, and want to see that works as expected. Just use the code you wrote, without Moq.

Moq is a library to use when you don't have (or want to use) an actual implementation, and just want to see what methods are invoked and/or control what is returned by the methods so you can test the caller.

So in your case you would create a Mock of the Repo if you want to see that Add is called in a certain scenario, or want to test what happens if Add throws an exception.

Comment: Hi Fried,

The whole point of this exercise is to test the functions internally. So in this case I want to test AddAFakeThing() and GetAllTheFakeThings(). This Fake repository should keep the data in a Database.

My question is, is there anyway to keep the data in the fake repository while you do the test?

Cheers

Comment: Your FakeRepo will do that, right? so just use 'new FakeRepo()', add some elements to that and pass it to your FakeService constructor. Don't bother with Moq.